# FILESTREAM vs VARBINARY for smaller files

Tags: sql-server, filestream

I could not find an exact answer to this here; please correct me if I'm wrong.

Is there a compelling reason to use `VARBINARY` for document files that have an expected median size of 40KB, with extremely rare outliers that can reach 2MB (when someone uploads a scan)?

According to Technet:

> [`FILESTREAM` is appropriate when] Objects that are being stored are, on average, larger than 1 MB.

...which in my case will be far from the truth.

The file table itself will be pretty small; 2000 files at the absolute limit. Bulk downloads will be limited to 10 files.

In this context, there may be no difference at all between `FILESTREAM` and `VARBINARY(MAX)`. Are there factors besides file size and bulk downloading to consider when making the choice?

Comment: An important factor is simplicity. For 2k files of 80MB in total, I'd not be concerned about performance.

Comment: According to [Microsoft](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/blogdoezequiel/2011/02/11/best-practices-on-filestream-implementations/) and based on my perf tests, varbinary is more performant up to about 1mb.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the performance perspective, there is no need for you to take the `FILESTREAM` route.

It does, however, have one other possible advantage over `VARBINARY(MAX)` -- an application can access it "directly" using `SqlFileStream`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is Filestream actually inferior for small files? Lets assume you have a large enough number of these files and concurrent users to see a real difference, if one does exist.

Comment: Yes. Check here, for example: http://sqltales.wordpress.com/2012/05/15/varbinary-vs-filestream-and-other-blob-issues-3/

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server 2008, if a varbinary column is defined to be stored as a file stream, the binary data is stored in a special folder structure which is managed by the SQL Server engine. The only thing that remains inside the database is a pointer to the file along with a mandatory GUID column in order to use the file stream from the Win32 client.
I think, it helps you to understand your issue.

Comment: This gives insight into the working of the server, but it doesn't answer the question.